# SmartGWT, TabSet, Move tab titles to the left

Tags: smartgwt

I have added a tabset with a few tabs to my GWT application, and now I would like to move the tabheaders a little bit to the left. Not the tab panes, but the small tab headers. These are positioned at the top of the tabset.

Does anyone know how to do this? I would prefer to do it programmatically, but am looking into how to do it with css as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so now I have solved the problem, but Im still hoping for a better and more easy solution. I copied the enterprise theme folder to my WAR (followed the quick start guide chapter 9). I edited the `load_skin.js` file, where I found the property named `layoutStartMargin` (in section6 for the Tabsets) and changed it to my desired indentation value.

I tried to invoke `TabSet.setProperty` with the name of the property and my value, but I got a JavaScriptException: (TypeError): widget is null It works, but I feel it could have done in another way. Any comments on this?